# SAP Business One: Connection Error When I try to connect to UI API

Tags: user-interface, connection, sapb1

I got this error message

```
 "Connection - Could not find SBO that match the connection string  [66000-85]"
```

when I try to connect SAP Business One UI API.

I connect like the following :

```
private void SetApplication()
{


    SAPbouiCOM.SboGuiApi SboGuiApi = null;  

    string sConnectionString = null;

    SboGuiApi = new SAPbouiCOM.SboGuiApi(); 

    // connect to a running SBO Application

    sConnectionString = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().GetValue(1).ToString() ;
    SboGuiApi.Connect(sConnectionString);     



    SBO_Application = SboGuiApi.GetApplication(-1); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it this problem, my connestring string is wrongly config. WHen I set rigth one it works now. Thanks all.